# Nucleophilicity of bonding vs lone pairs

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Does the bonding pair in $\ce{FeCl4^-}$ attack a proton or does a lone pair on the chlorine attack the proton?

[image]

My prof has an argument for the first one; the first one involves fewer steps, so it is probably more favorable. My proposed mechanism has three steps of electron pushing versus two, so okay.

However, I can see an argument for the second mechanism - the first one involves a bonding pair acting as a nucleophile rather than a lone pair on chlorine. The bonding pair is stabilized by the chlorine and the iron atom, while the lone pair is stabilized by only the chlorine.

So, which one wins? I'm guessing both mechanisms are operative here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your question, but we can speculate.  A lone pair is more sterically exposed than a bonding pair of electrons and therefor more accessible.  Also a lone pair is generally more nucleophilic because the electrons are concentrated in a smaller region since they are not being shared.  These two arguments would favor the second mechanism.  Finally, when we consider the SN2 reaction where, for example, water is the attacking nucleophile; I've never seen the mechanism drawn where the attacking electrons are from the O-H bond, but rather they always seem to show involvement of the lone pair electrons.  All of these arguments favor the second mechanism.

Comment: The example involves an analogous choice of which electron reservoir to tap.  I didn't think of it as an SN2, but isn't it really just a bimolecular, nucleophilic displacement?  It just has H at the center of things rather than carbon.

Comment: does the three vs two step argument hold water?

Comment: do you mean the "fewer steps are preferred" argument?

Comment: yes that's what i meant

Comment: Generally, when you're guessing about something, then yes.  But here, especially with electrons that move so quickly across very short distances, I think such an argument would have less significance - just my opinion.

Comment: is there a way to verify which mechanism is operative here? Or could it be that both are operative? Could we check by checking the orbitals that the lone pairs and bonding pairs are in? I.e. which one is in the higher HOMO?

Comment: The differences between the 2 mechanisms are pretty minor.  I don't think there is an experiment with high enough precision that could be done.  Perhaps a computational study.

Comment: just curious; what is your background? you seem to know more than all my profs combined

Comment: organic chemist, was a professor, moved to industry; I suspect your professors know more, but would rather spend time on their research than talk with students

Comment: last question for now; what orgo book do you recommend?

Comment: I haven't compared introductory organic texts in a while, but I like "Organic Chemistry" by M. Jones, Jr.

Comment: "Unlike every other organic chemistry book I've looked at, this book does not once use the excuse "...but that is beyond the scope of this course..."" ... sounds like the book for me @ron, thanks!